# Using MaxValue with complex argument

Tags: mathematical-optimization, complex

I know MaxValue is supposed to work with real numbers only, but there is some situations where a real valued function has complex terms anyway. Even with these complex terms, the function is still real valued. For example, consider the function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z)=|z|$. It's not hard to come up with a lot more examples.

I wonder whether exist a way to maximize functions like this using Mathematica. In this example in particular, I have the following code

```
s = Abs[a + I*b]^2;
MaxValue[{s, a^2 + b^2 <= 1}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

which Mathematica replies with `MaxValue::objc: The objective function Abs[a+I b]^2 contains a nonreal constant I. >>`.

When $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is clear that $|a+ib|^2$ is also real. In fact, the absolute value of *any* complex value is real, so why Mathematica is complaining about the imaginary number $i$ ? I know Mathematica is able to come up some simplification for this expression! Even without simlpification, Mathematica should know that the absolute value only outputs real values.

**PS:** the question is not about the example I gave, but about maximizing  complex expressions (functions) which will be real after some simplification.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `s` is real-valued you can probably convert it into an explicit real form using [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html). In some cases you may need to use the `ComplexExpand` option [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) to get an appropriate form. For example,

```
s = Abs[a + I*b]^2 // ComplexExpand

(*  a^2 + b^2  *)

MaxValue[{s, a^2 + b^2 <= 1}, {a, b}]

(*  1  *)
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working here. The command 

s = Abs[a + I*b]^2 // ComplexExpand 

still gives 

Abs[a + I b]^2

as output (and using MaxValue after gives the same problem).

Comment: @Integral - What Mathematica version and OS are you using? I am using v11.0.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: I'm using version 9. But nevermind, I just realized that TargetFunction->{Re,Im} solves the problem!