# Maximize a function over complexes

Tags: mathematical-optimization, complex, maximum

Assume that I have a bounded real valued function $h(a,b)$ such that $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and $b\in [0,1]$. Can Mathematica maximize such function over $\mathbb{C}\times [0,1]$?

I tried some functions such as `Maximize` and `NMaximize`, but following the documentation, they only consider real parameters.

**Edit:** Let's take the following example:

```
h[a_, b_] := (Abs[a] b)/(1 + Abs[a]);
Maximize[{h[a, b], 0 <= b <= 1}, {a, b}]
Out[1]={1, {a -> ComplexInfinity, b -> 1}}
```

From `ComplexInfinity` it seems that `a` is considered to be complex, but the documentation says that "If no domain is specified, all variables are assumed to be real".

As for `NMaximize`, it gives the following:

```
Out[2]={1., {a -> 1.2313*10^13, b -> 1.}}
```

meaning that `a` is (probably) conisdered to be real.

Comment: You're looking for an exact answer, right? Not a numerical one?

Comment: You can always write `a = x+iy` for real `x` and `y` and maximize that way.

Comment: Both or at least one of them.

Comment: @evanb I thought about it but I think that $\max_{a\in\mathbb{C}} \neq \max_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2}$.

Comment: While mathematically maximizing over $\mathbb{C}$ is exactly equivalent to using $a=x+iy$ and maximizing over $\mathbb{R}^2$, unfortunately, `Maximize` detects the presence of any `I` in its argument and returns an error, so this is not a viable solution. :(

Comment: One possible route, though, is writing out your complex number `a` as a $2\times 2$ matrix `{{a0, a1}, {-a1, a0}}`, using `Dot` (`.`) instead of `Times` when multiplying such representations of complex numbers together, modifying `Abs` appropriately, etc. Then maximizing over `a0, a1, b` (real) and including the constraint `0 <= b <= 1` in `Maximize` as usual should work—`Maximize` doesn't seem to have any problems with matrices. Of course, this would require rewriting your function `h`. This makes it surprising to me that it can't deal with complex numbers...maybe there's a better way...

Comment: An explicit example of $h$ would be very useful. Related: [(129266)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129266/27951).

Comment: As far as I can tell, though, `NMaximize` has no problem with `I`. `NMaximize[{h[x + I y, b], 0 <= b <= 1}, {x, y, b}]` should be fine.

Comment: (Let me know if either of these routes satisfies what you're looking for, and if so, I'll write it up as an answer when I get the chance!)

Comment: I edited my post..